# How to make different pages of auth() register pages by configuring routes with data defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-authorization, laravel-authentication

When I try to open Studentregister page it opens the default register page of auth().

I'm new in Laravel I m having issues with syntaxes...
I have made only one User class having link with role class.
(User class is generated through $php artisan auth and foreign key for Role class is added to it.)

Now I want to register different users like student, teacher through studentRegister.blade.php or teacherRegister.blade.php. And I have to fix role_id in student page as 1 and in teacher role id as 2. So what will be the syntax.

created different route for student register and teacher register (web.php) ..

```
Route::get('student/register','Auth\RegisterController@registerStudent');
Route::get('teacher/register','Auth\RegisterController@registerTeacher');
```

added role variable and send it to view (Auth/RegisterController.php)

```
  public function registerStudent()
  { $role_id = 1;
   return view('auth.register',compact('role_id'));
   }

  public function registerTeacher()
  { $role_id = 2;
   return view('auth.register',compact('role_id'));
   }
```

setted value of hidden input with "role" name (Auth/Register.Blade.php);

```
<input id="role" type="hidden" name="role" value="{{$role}}">
```

change fillable variable in user.php so you can fill role field.

```
protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'email', 'password',role ];
```

added role to your create function on RegisterController

```
**(Auth/RegisterController.php)**.
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'role' => $data['role'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

In StudentRegister.blade.php  I have added this

```
<input id="role_id" type="hidden" name="role_id" value="1">
```

In TeacherRegister.blade.php  I have added this

```
<input id="role_id" type="hidden" name="role_id" value="2">
```

Comment: is that $fillable role supposed to be a constant or a string?

Comment: When it comes to Auth, there are is a bunch of scaffolding in place.  If you take a look at `php artisan route:list` you may get a better sense of why you are being routed to that view.